# Will two web applications share the same session ID?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, sessionid

I have two ASP.NET web applications on the same server and domain, e.g. `myServer/app1` and `myServer/app2`.

`app1` reads `Session.SessionID` and then redirects to `app2`. **Will `app2` read the same `Session.SessionID` value?** Both applications run under the same application pool and use InProc session state.

*Background*: This works (same SessionID) on our server but fails to work on our customer's server (different SessionID). I'm trying to find out

- if we made wrong assumptions and it works just by accident on our server (why?) or
- the customer's server is misconfigured somehow.

Therefore, I'd like to know what's *supposed* to happen.

Comment: wondering if you redirect with `(url,false)` would make any difference, maybe its internal call to `Response.End` might be causing it to create a new session id for the next request.

Comment: @Heinzi You might want to read this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215737/how-to-maintain-the-same-session-id-across-multiple-web-applications-in-asp-net

Comment: @adatapost: Thanks. That seems to imply that the answer is *no* and that it is only working on our development server "by accident". I'd keep the question open, though, maybe someone can explain *why* it works like this.

Comment: Just to be sure... are both apps served from the same domain/subdomain on your costumer's server?

Comment: @ygormutti: If I remember correctly (it's an old issue), yes.